# Is it better to use EVP interface or call functions directly from Openssl?

Tags: c++, c, openssl

On Openssl's official website I read that its recommended to use `EVP` interface. But somewhere else, (can't find a link at the moment, just forgot) read that now we shouldnt use it any more, that its depreciated. Right, using `EVP` is much much easier but what is the **right** way to do it (not the easiest way)?

For example: I can do a MD5 hash in two ways with Openssl:

```
MD5(plaintext, strlen(plaintext), digest);
```

and:

```
MD5_CTX ctx;
MD5_Init(&ctx);
MD5_Update(&ctx, plaintext, strlen(plaintext));
MD5_Final(digest, &ctx);
```

Both solutions work but which one is correct and should be used nowadays?

Comment: A quick google find EVP (and all of OpenSSL) deprecated on Apple.